# Export a CSV File for a 'username' in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export-to-csv

I have data in a MySQL database. I am sending the participant a URL to get their data out as a CSV file. How can I, when they click the link, ...
A download link is there to download all data from the database in csv format.

```
<?php
$insquery = "SELECT username FROM r_institution where status=1";
    $exportstmt = $conn->query($insquery);
    $insresults = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exportstmt);
    foreach ($insresults as $rs) {
        $row = array();
        $row[] = stripslashes($rs["username"]);
        $content[] = $row;
    }
    $content = array();
    $title = array("username");
    foreach ($insresults as $rs) {
        $row = array();
        $row[] = stripslashes($rs["username"]);
        $content[] = $row;
    }
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fputcsv($output, $title);
    foreach ($content as $con) {
        fputcsv($output, $con);
    }
?>
```

Comment: please format your code

Comment: I for one, don't know what the question is about. Do you need to generate a button to fire that code up?

Comment: i want to generate a download csv file @Fred-ii-

Comment: Sorry but I still don't know what the question/problem is. What's wrong with what you posted? Any errors? Are you checking for them via PHP and MySQL? Is it a permissions issue? You didn't give us any infornation as to what's working or not.

Comment: A download link is there to download all data from the database in csv format. @Fred-ii-

Comment: I do not understand what you are after either!

Comment: You need to tell the browser that it is producing a CSV file and the file should be offered for download rather than displayed.  So you need to provide an HTTP header telling the browser what MIME type of the contents (text/csv).   For example: header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');  You can also use header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=mydata.csv'); where the value 'attachment' instructs the browser to offer the file for download with your suggested file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$filename = "testing-exports.csv";

    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    $insquery = "SELECT username FROM r_institution where status=1";
    //$exportstmt = $conn->query($insquery);
    $insresults = $conn->query($insquery);
    //$insresults = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exportstmt);
    foreach ($insresults as $rs) {
        $row = array();
        $row[] = stripslashes($rs["username"]);
        $content[] = $row;
    }
    $content = array();
    $title = array("Institution Emails");
    foreach ($insresults as $rs) {
        $row = array();
        $row[] = stripslashes($rs["username"]);
        $content[] = $row;
    }
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fputcsv($output, $title);
    foreach ($content as $con) {
        fputcsv($output, $con);
    }
```